# Auto complete address for search in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-google-places-autocomplete

I want to integrate autocomplete address population in search field using reactjs.
example when I enter a place related places with address is populated and we get the latitude and longitude also

sample react library is below
https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-places-autocomplete/v/1.9.3#live-demo
But above one is paid one.

Can I available any free library for this functionality and I am using functional component. Not need class component. I am new in React js. Thanks in advance

I tried one package, they provided installation step ,but that is using for class component. But I am using functional component.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autocomplete-places

Otherwise can we convert it into functional component? and if possible the how can convert it to functional component?

Comment: Have a read on this: https://tech.shaadi.com/2022/07/21/how-to-convert-class-components-to-function-components-in-react/

This explains how to convert a class component to a functional component. From the docs, it's seems doable to convert it to a functional component. You just have to convert the state to a `useState` hook, and convert the functions to have `const` (like how you usually define a function in a functional component) then remove all `this` keywords.

Comment: Also I installed google-api for this feature.For creating api key, google asked to enter the card details?Is there any free trial is available?

Comment: You would need to read more on this through the Google API docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replicating the example given in this article: [Places Autocomplete React](https://thepetersweeney.com/autocomplete-address/)